# How to close facebook's chatbox in Watir

Tags: watir

I'm currently struggling atm on closing [facebook's chatbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRCib.png) whenever my program goes to a page's page (intended kek). It pops up after a few secs upon page load completion. I cant seem to access elements inside it even if its already loaded specifically the "x button" at the top right as long as the chatbox has focus (header is blue).

```
@b.a(href: "https://www.facebook.com/"+handle+"/?ref=br_rs").click()    
@b.a(aria_label: "Close tab").wait_until_present.click()
```

Running the 2nd line returns a timeout error even though Im staring straight at it for 30secs. Magically (at least for me) the 2nd line runs if the chatbox loses focus (turns gray, mostly when i tab out). I've tried setting focus on some of the main page's element but to no avail. I can also close it if i do a send_keys but It requires me to add a sleep for like 3 seconds or so till the chatbox automatically opens upon page load but I heard adding hard coded sleep is not recommended. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doubt that FB wants you doing that, but...what's the HTML look like?

Comment: The second line runs perfectly, I don't face any issue. But I don't know which page are you trying to load in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this and it worked on Windows 10, watir 6.12, chromedriver 2.41, Chrome 68.0.3

```
 b.a(:'aria-label' => 'Close tab').click
```

For some reason it did not on my other machine, Ubuntu 16.04, Watir 6.11, chromedriver 2.40, Chrome 67.0.3

It magically worked after this

```
require 'watir'
p = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
p['enable_aria_label'] = true
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => p
sleep 40 #logged in manually and opened chat box 
b.a(:'aria-label' => 'Close tab').click
sleep 20
```

It closes first chat box it finds. You can close specific one via

```
b.as(:'aria-label' => 'Close tab')[0].click
```

Maybe it will work for you too.